# C++ static template function causes armcc compilation error (304)

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have tested compilation of the following code on both VS10 and armcc4.1 [Build 561]. Both functions depth1() and depth2() compile on VS, however armcc will only compile depth1() while giving an Error 304 (no instance of  matches the argument list) for depth2(). When foo and bar are non-static, it compiles fine on armcc as well.

I'd be happy to understand why.

```
template <class T>
static T foo(T arg)
{
   return arg*5;
}

template <class T>
static T bar(T arg)
{
   return foo<T>(arg);
}

void depth2()
{
   int i = 12;
   i = bar<int>(i);
}

void depth1()
{
   int i = 12;
   i = foo<int>(i);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. arm-eabi-gcc works fine as well. Probably something to do with foo<int> not existing before it tries to compile bar<int>

Comment: Thanks @Andres. From the error message., it appears that this is the case; however it is not clear why `bar` compiles while `foo` doesn't. Probably has to do with the depth of the templating required.

Comment: try defining first depth1() and then depth2(), or alternatively provide explicit instantiation of of foo<int>. Yes, it's a compiler bug and I provide possible workarounds here.

Comment: Any idea how to report such a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments above: This appears to be a bug in armcc 4.1.

If your employer has a support contract with ARM, you can raise a support issue with ARM here: http://www.arm.com/support/obtaining-support/index.php (click the "Development Tools" tab and then the big blue "Raise a Support Case" button).

As for workarounds, you might try

- rearranging the definitions of `foo` and `bar` in the source file; and/or
- providing a forward declaration for `foo` and/or `bar` somewhere prior to its definition; and/or
- adding an explicit instantiation of `foo<int>` somewhere after its declaration, like this:

  ```
  template int foo(int arg);
  // or, if you like this style better,
  template int foo<int>(int arg);
  ```

Comment: aren't you missing <> after template? `template<> int foo<int>(int arg);` , plus, I think you can also have `template<> int foo(int arg);`

Comment: @Kobi: No; `template<>` is the syntax for a full specialization. `template` is the syntax for an explicit instantiation, which is indeed what we want here. Shameless plug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwrXHznaYLA